# Counting unique text based on values from another column

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Need help to create a formula to count the cells with unique text in column A that has a non-zero value in column B.

[image: See picture here of worksheet]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1):

For similar data:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A21="Apples")*(B1:B21<>0))
```

[image]

similar for the other fruits.